# Subgraph of integral graph is also integral??

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

**Background:**  An integral graph is a graph whose spectrum consists entirely of integers (see [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_graph)]).

Example: Complete graph $K_n$, since spectrum$(K_n) = (n-1,-1,\ldots,-1)$

**Question** Is the induced subgraph of integral graph is also integral?

In otherwords this means are the eigenvalues of induced subgraph of intgral graph are also integers.

Or is $ \lambda_i \in \mathbb{N}$ ? where $\lambda_i $ is any eigenvalue of induced subgraph $H$ of integral graph $G$.

Note this is true for the case of complete graph.

**Idea** We know that the eigenvalues of induced subgraph interlace with that of the graph (see  Corollary 2.5.2 in [[2](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/spectra.pdf)] ). That would help us to determine some bounds for the eigenvalues of the induced subgraph.

Any help will be useful !!

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_graph)

[Book](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/2WF02/spectra.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not even close to true. The eigenvalues of the Petersen graph are integers, but it contains 5-cycles as induced subgraphs and these do not have integer eigenvalues. Or the eigenvalues of a 4-cycle are integers, but this contains paths on three vertices, which have non-integral eigenvalues. More generally note that the eigenvalues of the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$ are integers if and only if $mn$ is a perfect square; this leads to many more examples.